# nvidia-cuda docker container os, different from host

Tags: docker, nvidia-docker

In Nvidia's developer page (https://devblogs.nvidia.com/nvidia-docker-gpu-server-application-deployment-made-easy/)

It states that nvidia-docker provides "driver-agnostic CUDA images".
I would just like to inquire/clarify if this is only driver version specific or does this also apply to OS?

```
For example:
Host = CentOS
Docker Image/Container = Ubuntu
```

Does using nvidia-docker provide a way to utilize the CentOS's nvidia driver in the Ubuntu Docker Container?

Currently what I do is I always have 2 Docker files for supporting Ubuntu Host and CentOS Host and manually mount /dev/nvidia0 and copy the library files (or install the driver) inside the docker image.

I've asked this already to the Nvidia, but still waiting for them to answer.
I'll be trying it my self too to find out but I just thought to try my luck if anyone from SO already knows the answer.

Thank you in advance guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tested this and it does work.

"driver-agnostic CUDA images" is not only limitted to different versions of the driver but also across different OS (binary)

Thank you.